# How to get the stack of the original exception in a Failure <: Try

Tags: scala, try-catch, stack-trace

I have a piece of code that is wrapped in a `Try` for last resort safety. The output `Try[A]` is propagated through a couple of functions and managed somehow w.r.t the application.

Now, for debugging at dev time, I still would like to know where the actual error has happens, and if possible access the full stack. But all I found in the `Failure` object is an exception which has no stack. Is it possible to get it?

In my current situation, I get an IndexOutOfBoundException which could come from many places. But such type of problem will certainly arise many times for many other reasons.

Comment: `final case class Failure[+T](exception: Throwable) extends Try[T]` is just a container, if the exception has no stack, it doesn't depend on the `Failure` object but on who creates it

Comment: Who creatures the `Failure`? Perhaps you should show us your code

Comment: The failure is originally made by a `throw  new ...Exception`, and in my current case, somewhere outside my code (I must do somthing like `mySeq(i)` with `i>mySeq.size`. I would like to know where is the `mySeq(i)` that triggered the error. There are lots of places where that could happens, the code is 1000s of lines of numerical computation.

Comment: Is it the actual `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` or is it wrapped into something else? There is a school of thought in scala calling for not filling tracebacks when throwing exceptions, because they are apparently "expensive".  This is most likely what is happening in your case, and if so, there isn't much you can do about it, unfortunately.  Either way, this has nothing to do with the `Failure` or `Try` - they are not hiding the stack from you, if it was there, you would see it.

Comment: bad luck  then. Is there some alternative to Try that would provide the same benefit but allow to easily force the error at dev time? We added the Try because we cannot allow a full run to fail in prod because of an error, but [error are not suppose to happens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law): when we find one, we correct it.

Comment: Like I said, it has nothing to do with `Try`. If your are not seeing the stack, the problem is at the place, that threw the exception, not where it got caught.

Comment: ok, I did not get it. I corrected the error and I don' t remember which exact exception it was. I will check next time. That's a pretty rash decision to not keep the trace in exceptions... At least it should be a compilation option.

Comment: It's not a built-in scala feature, but a prorgammer's choice, so, it could not be a compilation option, but I agree with you that the decision is rather rash (and, IMO, largely unfounded).